# Packable pillow for side-sleepers that actually work?

Tags: gear, sleeping

After fondling & buying various pillows from the local travel stores & hours of research online over the years I have yet to find a foldable pillow that actually is "firm" enough to support a side sleeper. They all squish too flat though they look "fluffy" in the beginning.I want it to be firm enough to support reading a book while lying flat too. I'm looking for a rectangular pillow which is "compressible" in some way (preferably stuffs into it's own sack + has a non-slippery surface) for use on beds/flat surfaces and not plane seats etc. Anybody know of a travel pillow that fits?

Edit: Oops, forgot to say: No inflatables please.  Oh, the nightmares.  ;-)

Edit 2.0: I don't care how tiny the pillow might be as long as it has enough support. In my daily life I use a foam type pillow (the cheapie foam not the Tempur-stuff. Though I'd to avoid the sore ears I get from my daily pillow. So if a travel sized one exists like that it would be good...where are all you pillow-carrying-sidesleepers at? :-)  What do you use?

Comment: is your objection to the inflatables that they are slippery and rubbery? Because they don't have to be.

Comment: @Kate No, I like have a fear of inflatables...lol...after the one year I spent on inflatable beds that broke so often when I was totally exhausted of course...

Comment: I find pillows that are found in first class in many airlines are good, they are medium in size, can be compressed, and really firm.

Comment: @MeNoTalk But do they come with a cover of some sort to be compressed?  Or do you mean you can just squish them into luggage?  All pillows can be squished anyway...?  Where can you buy those?

Comment: @pnuts Then how do you know it works if it doesn't even exist? ;-)

Comment: I use my jumper.

Answer (score 2):

Use your clothes. You're already packing them.  If they don't hold sufficient form, carry a pillow case and put a few items of clothing inside--either folded, or wadded, depending on the texture/form you desire.

If this isn't soft enough, carry one of your existing travel pillows and place it between the pillow case and clothing for an added layer of padding.

Comment: I really am looking for a pre-made solution.  Don't wanna wrinkle 'em clothes.  ;-)

Comment: Your clothes will already get wrinkled if you put them in a suitcase.

Answer (score 1):

I usually just use my large towel and fold it down to pillow size.

Towels are just about the most massively useful thing any traveller can carry. It fits all your pillow requirements and you probably already have one in your luggage, so you don't need to buy anything or carry an extra item in your backpack.

Comment: [Relevant](http://hitchhikers.wikia.com/wiki/Towel)

Comment: This doesn't work so well if you use one of [these towels](http://amzn.to/1DCtXZS) like I do.

Comment: I use a Packtowel that stuffs into a sack...definitely would not want to sleep on a towel for a month anyway.  :-)

Comment: @Flimzy Ooh, another user!!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care people staring at you thinking you are a completely insane person, you can try the [ostrich pillow](http://www.ostrichpillow.com).

[image: ostrich on a table]

[image: ostrich in traveling]

They have other types of pillows on their website.

Comment: LOL...seen those but just looking for a standard hotel style pillow.

Comment: All of their pillows can only be spot cleaned.  Too un-hygienic for me after using it on countless surfaces.  They should make covers?

Comment: I used to be desperate about hygiene, I gave up after going to France. *I'm not saying french people don't have hygiene*, but fact is in my culture I'm used to wash my hands after using public transport, using money, before lunching... and in Paris a woman cut a slice of bread, using the same hands that got the coins I gave to her. I have an ostrich, it's confortable though. They have other types on their website, some small ones that maybe you can clean in a different way.